# Azor's paradox resonator

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a least one [Paradox Haze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParadox%20Haze%5d) on the battlefield, and during my upkeep tap the [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) targeting [Azor's Elocutors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAzor%27s%5d%2b%5bElocutors%5d) upkeep ability, would the ability copy twice or would I need a second Resonator?

Comment: Tip: You could copy Paradox Haze's ability just as easily as the Elecutor's. This would allow you to benefit from multiple "At the beginning of your upkeep" abilities.

Comment: Good point slipt my mind I guess. Either option give the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability would just copy once, and you would end up with a total of 3 filibuster counters after both upkeeps.

Paradox Haze gives you a second upkeep step. That just literally means that after one upkeep, another one happens. At the start of each of those 2 upkeep steps, Azor's ability will trigger, go on the stack, and resolve.

You activate Strionic Resonator during the first upkeep step or the second; either way there will be 1 copy of Azor's ability on the stack at that time, which you can target and copy.

To copy both of them for a total of 4 counters, you would need to also untap Strionic so you can use it a second time (or have another Strionic).

Comment: Would you have any good replacements for the resonator?  Aside from obviously more paradox haze on the field

Comment: @LordShadowheim there are plenty of things such as Voltaic Key that can untap the Resonator to let you use it again. That seems like one of the simplest ways.

Answer (score 3):

**Your [Azor's Elocutors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=265418) will end up with 3 filibuster counters.**

The step by step of the interaction will work as follows:

1. It is the beginning of your turn. You have your untap step, you untap everything and proceed to the next step.
2. It is your Upkeep. [Paradox haze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=109721) triggers and will creates a second upkeep that we will get to later.
3. Azor's Elecutors triggers. The ability goes onto the stack.
4. You respond to Azor's Elecutors ability by tapping [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370670) targeting the Azor's Elecutors "add a filibuster counter" ability on the stack. If the other player doesn't respond with effects of their own, the stack begins to resolve.
5. Strionic Resonator's copy ability resolves, there are now two "add a filibuster counter" abilities on the stack.
6. The copied "add a filibuster counter" ability resolves. **Azor's Elecutors now has one filibuster counter.**
7. The orginal "add a filibuster counter" ability resolves. **Azor's Elecutors now has two filibuster counters.**
8. **End of 1st Upkeep.** Because of Paradox Haze's ability you will get an additional Upkeep.
9. It is your second Upkeep of the turn. Paradox Haze dosen't trigger this time.
10. Azor's Elecutors triggers. The ability goes on the stack.
11. This time your Strionic Resontor is tapped so you can't copy it again.
12. Assuming no response from your opponent, Azor's Elecutors ability resolves. **Azor's Elecutors now has two filibuster counters.**
13. **End of 2nd Upkeep.** You proceed to your draw phase and the rest or your turn.

As you can see you only receive 3 filibuster counters total. This is because ([from gatherer rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370670)):

> Strionic Resonator targets a triggered ability that has triggered and is on the stack.

Strionic works by copying an ability that has already triggered, not by causing the ability to trigger twice. That is why Azor's Elecutors only ends up with 3 counters.

Comment: Paradox Haze has a triggered ability, but it does not create a delayed triggered ability. It doesn't really matter in this case though, so good answer overall.

Comment: @Rainbolt whoops, you are correct, I misinterpreted the card as "get an additional upkeep after the first finishes" instead of "get an additional upkeep". Corrected now